# Recursive function Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I try to call this function in the URL as I am working in CI,
www.example.com/tree/get_parent/3432/1

It gives me 1 instead of 1,2,3,4. I don't know what the problem in that code? I don't know why it doesn't call itself 4 times

> public function get_parent($id,$n)    {
>   if($n==5){ return 1; }
>
> else {
>     echo $n;
>         $n++;
>     return get_parent($id,$n);
>   }
>              }

Any help is really appreciated. thanks

Comment: it is a function or a method? (if it is, show the context)

Comment: Just solved the problem by knowing the difference between the method and the function. thank you Peter!

Answer (score 0):

looks like your not calling the right method, try:

```
return $this->get_parent($id,$n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just take out the `return` in the `else` statement

```
public function get_parent($id,$n) {
    if($n==5){ return 1; }

    else { 
        echo $n;
        $n++;
        get_parent($id,$n);
    } 
}
```